# Trying to find " " in an array with regular expressions in VBA (office 2010)

Tags: regex, vba

I'm looking in an array, created from Split() of an email body, for spaces (" "), to ignore them.

I've tried array(i) = " " and srtComp (array(i), " ", vbTextCompare).
In debug mode I see that the array element is indeed " ", but it doesn't recognize it. Now I'm trying wiht regular expressions and my code looks like this:

```
    Set reg = New RegExp
With reg
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = " +"
End With

'~~> Write to excel
With oXLws
    '
    strBody = Split(olMail.Body)

    For i = 0 To UBound(strBody)

        If strBody(i) Like "*Hora:*" Then

            i = i + 1
            Set MyMatches = reg.Execute(strBody(i))

            While MyMatches.Count <> 0
                i = i + 1
                Set MyMatches = reg.Execute(strBody(i))
            Wend

            .Range("B" & lRow).Value = strBody(i + 1)
            i = i + 1

        End If

    Next i

    '
End With
```

The MyMatches.Count <> 0 condition is not working either, it never enters the cicle.
Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I very much suspect that you have too many occurrences of `i = i + 1` in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unprintable characters aren't always spaces (ASCII 32). If it comes from an HTML email, it's probably ASCII 160.  Try this sub to see what your single character array elements are, then you'll know what to look for. You'll have to figure out how to set olMail, but I assume you're doing that already.

```
Sub TestWhiteSpace()

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim vaBody As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    vaBody = Split(olMail.Body, Space(1))

    For i = LBound(vaBody) To UBound(vaBody)
        If Len(vaBody(i)) = 1 Then
            Debug.Print i, Chr$(vaBody(i)), vaBody(i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```